# Toggle button animation

Tags: javascript, css

I have a toggle button to switch the website background color from black to white (and vice versa). It works ok, but I want the slider to move slowly (in 1 second, not instantly) when I click on it. The code:

```js
var change = function() {
  var backgr = document.body,
  slider = document.getElementById('slider');

  if (backgr.style.backgroundColor == 'white') {
    backgr.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
    slider.style.float = 'right';
  } else {
    backgr.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
    slider.style.float = 'left';
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}

#toggle {
  width: 30px;
  height: 16px;
  background-color: orange;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 16px;
}

#slider {
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 1px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<button id='toggle' onclick="change()">
  <span id='slider'></span>
</button>
```

Comment: You cannot transition/animate changing float direction over a period of time. You should instead look at animating `transform` properties.

Comment: As others have said, use the [transition property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transition.asp) (which does not work on float)

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if you have to animate the `background-color` or the button so I have animated both with a CSS transition, so keep just what you need.

For the button I've simply changed the `margin-right` (via `calc()`) keeping the `float: right` (which it can't be animated)

Also the JS part is simplified: toggling a class on the `body` element is enough and you can keep off your style from Javascript so as a result your code is more mantainable.

```js
   
var body = document.body;
var change = function() {
  body.classList.toggle('active');
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  transition: background-color 1s;
}
body.active {
  background-color: white;
}

#toggle {
  width: 30px;
  height: 16px;
  background-color: orange;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 16px;
}

#slider {
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 1px;
  transition: margin 1s;
  border-radius: 50%;
  float: right;
}

.active #slider {
   margin-right: calc(100% - 15px);
}
```

```html
<button id='toggle' onclick="change()">
  <span id='slider'></span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

Rather than using a button, I'd reskin a checkbox like this. This is handy as it keeps track of its own boolean value.

Then based on whether or not it's checked you can do whatever.

Below I've used transform and transition to animate the sliding you can see this in the CSS.

```js
function toggleChange(e) {
  let bodyStyle = document.querySelector('body').style;
  if (e.target.checked) {
    bodyStyle.background = "#000";
  } else {
    bodyStyle.background = "#FFF";
  }
}
```

```css
.switch[type=checkbox] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  position: relative;
  width: 30px;
  height: 16px;
  background-color: orange;
  border-radius: 16px;
}

.switch[type=checkbox]::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background: #FFF;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  border-radius: 7px;
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  margin: 1px;
}

.switch[type=checkbox]:checked::after {
  transform: translateX(14px);
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" onchange="toggleChange(event)" class="switch" />
```

I hope this is helpful.

Comment: could you please explain why do you use `[type=checkbox]` in your css?

Comment: @ignor234 I put that in there so the switch class can be used in other places. With this set up only a checkbox with the switch class will be affected by the CSS. It's not something you have to do it's just my style.

Answer (score 2):

Use `transition: left 1000ms ease;`
and `position: relative;`

Then change the `left` property in the script instead of changing `float`:

```js
var change = function() {
  var backgr = document.body,
    slider = document.getElementById('slider');

  if (backgr.style.backgroundColor == 'white') {
    backgr.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
    slider.style.left = 0; // NEW LINE
  } else {
    backgr.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
    slider.style.left = "15px"; // NEW LINE
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}

#toggle {
  width: 30px;
  height: 16px;
  background-color: orange;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 16px;
}

#slider {
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 1px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  float: left; /* NEW LINE */
  position: relative; /* NEW LINE */
  transition: left 1000ms ease; /* NEW LINE */
  left: 0; /* NEW LINE */
}
```

```html
<button id='toggle' onclick="change()">
      <span id='slider'></span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of float, I think you should use css that can by used with transition. if you place your sldier with a position for example, you can add a transition on the position with a 1sec duration and it will works as you want